# Проблема пробела txt файла при использовании в PHP

Tags: php, html

Вот код программы:

```
<?php
$file="cena3.txt";
$open=fopen($file,"r+");
$read=fread($file,100000);
fclose($open);
echo "<form action=redaktor.php method=GET>";
echo "<input type=text value=$read name=cena1>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

в переменную $read я вписываю значение с пробелом (под заказ) и он нарушает html код страницы... Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не забывайте про экранирование, пример :

```
echo "<form action=\"redaktor.php\" method=\"GET\">";
```

Либо использование других кавычек :

```
echo '<form action="redaktor.php" method="GET">';
```

Обычно для значений атрибутов используют двойные кавычки.

Answer (score 4):

Использовать кавычки в параметрах тегов, конечно же. Всегда.
Пример:

```
echo "<form action='redaktor.php' method='GET'>";
echo "<input type='text' value='$read' name='cena1' />";
echo "</form>";
```

Конечно, если в переменной образуются кавычки подобные, то тег нарушится. Но, понятное дело, этого легко избежать.

Comment: Честно говоря нереально бесит когда у атрибутов нет ковычек, это нереальный быдло код.

Comment: Пережитки тёмных времён...

Answer (score 1):

Не забывай использовать ковычки